# Exception (special exclusion) in route parameters

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, angular-routing

I have the following route definition in my `app-routing.module.ts`:

`{ path: 'messages/:id', loadChildren: './pages/message/message.module#MessagePageModule' },`

However, I have a page that loads archived messages. Naturally, the path for this page would be something like `messages/archived`. However, this conflicts with the route that's already defined with an ID for the message page i.e. `messages/:id`.

How can I define an exception that if `id == 'archived'`, it should load the page with archived messages?

Further info: the ID in messages is always numeral, i.e. in real time it would be something like `messages/123`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggetsion: You should use query params for archived messages as this is type of messages not a different resource, whereas :id is a single resource.

Solution: Change the order of archived route as below:

In app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'messages', loadChildren: './pages/message/message.module#MessagePageModule' }
```

In message-routing.module.ts

```
const messageRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'archived',
            component: ArchivedComponent
        },
        {
            path: ':id',
            component: MessageComponent
        },
        {
            path: '',
            component: MessageComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
        }
    ]
 }
```

As order of the route matters explained [here](https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/angular-route-ordering/). This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is very close to the solution I was looking for, although another complication rises as I already have a route defined for the path `messages`.

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code and it can handle your scenario. You can read lazy loading and routing in angular